# How to apply outlook rule based on Sender's Address instead of Sender's Name with rule wizard alone?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, exchange-2016

I am trying to apply outlook rule for mails sent from xyz@company.com address. In the global address list, xyz@company.com has "XYZ Name". However, the sender uses different names for xyz@company.com.

Now while creating the rule when I mention the sender's mail id, it automatically picks the sender name and saves the rule with sender name.

Thus, when the actual mail arrives with a different sender name, the rule doesn't apply on it.

How to save the rule with sender's mail id alone?

I do not want to use VBA script as it will only work while my desktop outlook is opened. And having the contact saved locally also is not a feasible solution, as the sender names are not restricted to a list and keeps changing with new person using the application.

Also checking for word in From Address is workable solution, but I am not like it much as it can be buggy and redirect mails by identifying subtexts.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/386264/how-to-normalize-sender-names-in-outlook?rq=1 has similar question, but it doesn't work for Outlook rules

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally, we can use the rule “with specific words in the sender’s address” which looks at the SMTP address of the sender and not its actual display name.

Besides, to use the rule “from people or public group”, instead of selecting names of your Address Book, we can also type the word (new name) that you want the rule to search for. When Check Names window pop up, click cancel.

Comment: "When Check Names window pop up, click cancel." This is so unintuitive, but it actually works.